# asp.net div Images not displayed in few Client machine

Tags: asp.net

I have developed a Web Application where i have these following pages and their corresponding Problematic tags.

### Login Page :

```
      <div id="maindiv" runat="server" style="background-image: inherit; height: 997px;">  
        &nbsp;            
<img id="Img1" runat="server" src="images/Login1.jpg" 
         style="width: 100%; height: 978px" alt="" />
```

### Master Page:

```
   <div id="Div1" style="position: absolute">
                <img src="images/Circle_300.jpg" style="height: 132px; width: 159px" />
            </div>
   and 

    <div id="logo">
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:Panel ID="ImgagePanel" runat="server"  
        BackImageUrl="~/images/Logo_2.jpg" Height="100%" 
         Width="100%" > </asp:Panel>
     </div>
```

I have all those Images under "images" directory in the application. the images are getting displayed well and good in all our office environment systems and outside client machines too. but the same not getting displayed in my real Client office systems..but the div tag with "Div1" alone is getting displayed in their systems.but not other images. Don't know where im going wrong. Please help me out.

One More Info: When I right click and save on the place where image is to be displayed  i get "blockedpage.gif" instead of the real image in the site whereas I can save the images from my machine. is it something with their security settings ?

Comment: The systems in which this is not displayed, which browser is used to see the page?

Comment: Chrome and IE..Chrome is atleast displaying the "DIV1" image alone but IE is displaying no images.

Comment: I am not sure how is your login page working as there is no contentplaceholder in master page. But try removing "style="position: absolute" from Div1.

Comment: Login page is a separate page and when user logs in i redirect to Master page and I have contentplaceholder in Masterpage.